# reset game in processing

Tags: processing

I am making a Tron game in Processing. I have the game all worked out but I do not know how to add a reset option to start a new game after the player loses.

Anyone have some suggestions?

Comment: You have to be more specific to get an answer here. Read http://stackoverflow.com/faq

Answer (score 1):

Well usually you should  make a method that will reset/recreate/delete what is needed to restart your game. Like(pseudo):

```
    void reset(){
     score = 0;
     ballsList.removeAll();
     playerPositionX = 0; 
     playerPositionY = 0;
    }
```

And then call it when needed.
Avoid using "init" as name of the method or you will override a built in method.

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't a simple switch case work fine ?

```
Switch (levels):

Case one:

Case last level:

If (this == that){
levels = one;
break
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What I would say is wrap your whole gamecode in a function like `void inGame(){gamecodeing}` and when something happens like `if (player.state == "dead"){inGame();}` and the ingame at the starting as well. Like so:

```
void setup() {
    size(500,500);
}
void draw() {
    inGame();
    if (playerHasLost) {inGame();}
}
void inGame() {gameStuff}
```

and every time `inGame()` is called it kind of does it all over again.

Answer (score -1):

I'd reccomend running the `setup()` again.
And then store your variables in there like `x = 0;`, `score = 0;`.